# How can I edit an image linked to a jQuery radio box when that radio box option is selected?

Tags: jquery, css, radio-button

I am using a jQuery radio box to create a questionnaire, and each option in the radio box has a corresponding image linked such that the image can be clicked to select that radio box option. I have also used javascript and css to make the radio box visually responsive to clicks: if you select one image, the radio box circle at the bottom of the selected image is outlined in green, and every other non-selected radio box circle is then outlined in red (see image below). Eventually I plan to hide the circular radio inputs using "input {visibility:hidden;}. My problem is that I want the red and green outlines to appear around the linked images instead, but I can't figure out how to alter the whole image rather than just the tiny radio box circle. (Also, please disregard the images, these are just temporary to make my styling easier so I can see what it will look like.)

This is what my HTML, CSS, and JS look like right now:

```js
$('input:radio[name=movie]').change(function() {
  const unCheckedInputs = $('input:radio[name=movie]').not(":checked");
  unCheckedInputs.addClass('inputRemoved');
  $(this).removeClass('inputRemoved');
});
```

```css
.answers input:checked {
  transition: all 0.5s;
  outline: 10px solid rgb(72, 151, 52); //green
}

.inputRemoved {
  transition: all 0.5s;
  outline: 10px solid rgb(158, 47, 47); //red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="answers">

    <label> //answer 1
        <div class="image">
            <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/W/IMAGERENDERING_521856-T1/images/I/61CsXp-qnnL.jpg" />    
        </div>
        <input type="radio" name="movie" value="horror" class="radioElement"/>
    </label>

    <label> //answer 2
        <div class="image">
            <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0057/3728/3618/products/a39764b3dd2055b6cd783ec77bcab5eb_3cc8ea63-bb5e-4759-bb2b-5b08e2cf3d6c_grande.jpg?v=1573585473" />
        </div>
        <input type="radio" name="movie" value="romance" class="radioElement"/>
    </label>

    <label> //answer 3
        <div class="image">
            <img src="https://www.lucasfilm.com/app/uploads/IJ1-IA-241_R-480x711.jpg" />
        </div>
        <input type="radio" name="movie" value="action" class="radioElement"/>
    </label>
</div>
```

The two screenshots below are what the page looks like before and after clicking on the middle image. My goal for the "after" would be to have the green outline around the second image, and the red outlines to be around the first and third images (instead of around the circular radio boxes below, which will be hidden). Thank you so much for your help in advance!

page before clicking middle image

[image: page before clicking middle image]

page after clicking middle image

[image: page after clicking middle image]

I tried replacing the JS above with

```
  $('.radioElement').change(function() {
    $(this)
      .removeClass('inputRemoved')
      .siblings()
      .addClass('inputRemoved')
  });
```

which for whatever reason made an outline appear around a selected image, but the outline never disappeared whenever a new image was selected, and the non-selected images were never outlined, so I went back to the other JS. I also tried to write my CSS so that it would change my .image class if "inputRemoved" was added but did not have any success actually getting that method to work.

Comment: The radio buttons aren't siblings of each other. Each radio button is nested inside a different `<label>`.

Comment: @Barmar Is this incorrect/would you suggest making them siblings then? I apologize, I'm very new to HTML.

Comment: `$(this).closest("label").siblings()...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There no needs to use js code.
Simply use CSS.

```js
const myForm = document.querySelector('#my-form');

// disable form submitting == page reload on submit
myForm.onsubmit = e => e.preventDefault(); 


myForm.oninput = () => 
  {
  myForm.classList.toggle('Activ', myForm.imgSelect.value !== '');
  };                                   //  ^-- use child name
```

```css
label { 
  display : inline-block;
  margin  : 10px;
  }
label input[type="radio"] {
  display : none; 
  }
label input[type="radio"] + img {
  border  : 5px solid transparent;
  }
#my-form.Activ label input[type="radio"] + img {
  border-color : lightcoral;
  }
#my-form.Activ label input[type="radio"]:checked + img {
  border-color : green;
  }
```

```html
<form id="my-form">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="imgSelect" value="img_A">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/100/150?random=1">
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="imgSelect" value="img_B">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/100/150?random=2">
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="imgSelect" value="img_C">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/100/150?random=3">
  </label>
</form>
```

> PO comment : Another question about your solution--when implementing this syntax for multiple consecutive questions in my questionnaire,
>
> > Not sure I understood the change from your comment.Maybe the answer

*Otherwise, I stop there. Asking questions to drawers is not acceptable here. Post a new question.

Take care to write your question completely from the beginning, otherwise it becomes endless*

**T**he idea remains the same, the active class is on the parent of the radio button series.
(here it is on `<fieldset>` element)

Also added a reset.

```js
const 
  myForm = document.querySelector('#my-form')
, radioFields =
    ['child1','child2','child3']
    .map( radioBtn => ({ radioBtn, fiSet: myForm[radioBtn][0].closest('fieldset')}))
    ; 
myForm.onsubmit = e => e.preventDefault(); // disable form submitting == page reload on submit

myForm.onreset = () =>  // for testing clear
  {
  radioFields.forEach(({radioBtn,fiSet }) => fiSet.classList.remove('Activ'));
  }
myForm.oninput = () => 
  {
  radioFields.forEach(({radioBtn,fiSet }) => fiSet.classList.toggle('Activ',myForm[radioBtn].value !== ''));
  }
```

```css
fieldset {
  width         : fit-content;
  margin-bottom : 10px;
  }
label { 
  display : inline-block;
  margin  : 10px;
  }
label input[type="radio"] {
  display : none; 
  }
label input[type="radio"] + img {
  border  : 5px solid transparent;
  }
fieldset.Activ label input[type="radio"] + img {
  border-color : lightcoral;
  }
fieldset.Activ label input[type="radio"]:checked + img {
  border-color : green;
  }
```

```html
<form id="my-form">
  <fieldset>
    <legend> child 1 </legend>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="child1" value="img_A">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/100/150?random=1">
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="child1" value="img_B">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/100/150?random=2">
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="child1" value="img_C">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/100/150?random=3">
    </label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend> child 2 </legend>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="child2" value="img_A">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/100/150?random=4">
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="child2" value="img_B">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/100/150?random=5">
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="child2" value="img_C">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/100/150?random=6">
    </label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend> child 3 </legend>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="child3" value="img_A">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/100/150?random=7">
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="child3" value="img_B">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/100/150?random=8">
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="child3" value="img_C">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/100/150?random=9">
    </label>
  </fieldset>

  <button type="reset"> clear All </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response--the reason I think I may need JS is that I don't want colors to appear at all until after one option has been selected. Then, I want the selected option to have green and the non-selected options to have red. Apologies for my miscommunication

Comment: This is exactly what I was hoping it would look like, thank you so much for your  help!

Comment: @eleanor If my answer suits you, you are supposed to validate it. This is how this site works to distinguish the helpful answer.

Comment: @eleanor  see last update

Comment: So sorry for the confusion caused by my cut-off comment, I thought I edited it successfully but I must've done something wrong. I'm still learning how to use stack overflow :) Thank you for all of your help.